# Adding html list items dynamically from code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

The above is the code in my .aspx page.
How this can be added from code behind dyanmically?

```
<ul runat="server" id="1">
<li><a href="page.html">abc</a>
  <ul runat="server" id="2">
  <li><a href="pag2.htm">3</a></li>
  <li><a href="page3.htm">2</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'd suggest using a repeater with a nested bulletedlist control. But I hope the data is only one level deep...?

Answer (score 0):

You must use the "InnerHtml" property of "sidebarmenu1" control.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.loadHtml();
        }
```

So you can generate every list item code and add it to the InnerHtml:

```
private loadHtml()
{
    this.sidebarmenu1.InnerHtml = GetListHtml().ToHtmlString();
}
```

And a little example for this GetListHtml:

```
public string GetListHtml()
        {
            StringBuilder htmlBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            htmlBuilder.AppendLine("<li><a href="#">Flat</a>");
            htmlBuilder.Append("<ul runat="server" id="sidebarmenu2">");
            htmlBuilder.AppendLine("<li><a href="#">Flat 1`enter code here`</a></li>");
            htmlBuilder.Append("<li><a href="#">Flat 2</a></li></ul>");
            return htmlBuilder.ToString();
        }
```

This GetListHtml method can call to a DAL or load data from any other place... use a foreach to load every item...

Comment: i guess the string (attribute values) you have enclosed in double quotes will not work. eg:htmlBuilder.AppendLine("<li><a href="#">Flat</a>"); must be replaced with htmlBuilder.AppendLine("<li><a href='#'>Flat</a>"); the attribute values must be enclosed with single quotes right?

Answer (score 0):

you can take the analogy of the tutorial given in this link :
http://neimke.blogspot.com/2011/01/create-delicious-user-interface-for.html
it worked for me - It dynamically adds the list items using the given code below using jquery .. check it pout ...

```
 <li id="tagInputListItem"><input class="tagInput" id="tagInput" /></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put a PlaceHolder in your .aspx and give it an id, then use that id in code behind page and add controls to that placeholder.
For more information you can see in [here.](http://www.developerfusion.com/code/3826/adding-controls-to-placeholders-dynamically/)

And if you're really sure about "runat=server" attribute maybe this post of mine it's useful ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120695/dynamically-created-dropdownlist-no-firing-event-yes-autopostback-is-set-to-tru/7244401#7244401))

If you need clarifications give me a feedback.

Comment: You can use Controls only for those <ul runat="server"> and put for their InnerHtml the respective <li>.But for those tags with "runat='server'" you can't do it without using asp controls. So you'll have to use HtmlGenericControls("ul").

Answer (score 0):

You can use ASP Literal to populate data from back-end code
eg. if you have literal with id ltrNavigation

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       ltrNavigation.text = "";
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
           ltrNavigation.text += "<ul id='sidebarmenu1'>";
           ltrNavigation.text += "<li><a href='#'>Flat</a></li>";
           ltrNavigation.text += "</ul>";
        }

}
```